# Lenovo Yogi 2 How to change Windows 8 core installation language to English?

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I purchased Lenovo Yogi 2 in Poland whilst on holidays there. Changed Region/Language etc but all startups/shutdown dialog boxes etc are still in Polish.

Comment: There's no need to call the support. Just wait a bit here. If you've changed the ui language successfully, you'll just have to apply that to a special/hidden user to make it global. Can't look it up right now, but I'm sure someone will help you soon.

Comment: if you can, post a few details for others as an answer, so others might follow the steps as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Re-posting the OP's self-answer portion of the question as an answer to conform with the site's Q&A structure.*

After much research and save yourself some angst is that I have found the ONLY way to resolve this successfully is that to bite the bullet go onto Microsoft online 24/7 chat whereby they can access your laptop remotely, uninstall the country's original language Microsoft pack and install Microsoft English at a cost of $119 for one time fee or 12mths support for $199.00!

Also it doesn't pay to buy any laptops in a foreign country/language (unless it's in your language) because as I have just found out that in my case Australia, will NOT support any purchase from overseas!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a guide (with pictures!) that leads you through the steps of changinge the lanugage. The language in the pictures is english but all you have to do is click the same buttons accordingly since they are in the same position. Good Luck.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-change-the-system-language-in-windows-8/

Comment: What about Windows 10 now pls?

Comment: Well which part of the guide does not apply for you on Windows 10? Go to the Control Panel by pressing `Windows Key + Q`, enter "control panel" and click the link. Proceed with steps in the guide.